# Почему принимают на грудь?

Tags: фразеология

Один из синонимов выпивки - это "принять на грудь". А почему так говорят? Моя версия: это связано с петровской медалью, которую он вешал на пьяниц. Ошибаюсь я или нет?
Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

В русском языке существует  большое количество соматических фразеологизмов, или соматизмов, связанных с различными частями тела: грудью, спиной, шеей, руками.  Например: дышать полной грудью, проложить грудью дорогу, встать грудью на защиту чего-либо, биться грудь с грудью.

Фразеологизм "принять на грудь" относится к таким соматизмам. Отметим, что в каждом конкретном случае слово "грудь" переосмысливается, употребляется в каком-либо переносном значении. В нашем примере это выглядит примерно так:

а) ПРИНЯТЬ НА СЕБЯ - ПРИНЯТЬ НА ГРУДЬ.В языковом сознании ГРУДЬ воспринимается как та часть тела, которая первой принимает удары или иные внешние воздействия.

б) ПРИНЯТЬ ЛЕКАРСТВО - ПРИНЯТЬ СПИРТНОЕ.Здесь опущенный при переходном глаголе объект переосмыслен "по умолчанию".

Таким образом шутливо идеализируется процесс выпивания спиртного как смелый поступок,  мужество и доблесть по отношению к "опасности".

Материал по ссылке http://www.dslib.net/jazyki-mira/telesnyj-kod-v-kitajskoj-frazeologii-i-ego-russkoe-sootvetstvie.html

В заключение интересная история со "змеей, пригретой на груди".

"Есть мнение, что фразеологизм «змею на груди пригреть» появился вместе с басней «Крестьянин и змея», написанной древнегреческим баснописцем Эзопом. Один земледелец, обнаружив на своем поле замерзшую змею, решил отогреть ее у себя за пазухой. Но ползучая тварь не оценила заботы крестьянина и, согревшись, ужалила его. Мораль: излишняя доверчивость до добра не доведет".

Answer (score 0):

Любителям горячительного (на судостроительных верфях) при Петре ставили печать на шею ниже скулы, собственно от туда и пошел известный жест. В деревнях Нижегородской области часто слышу "принять на грудь" в смысле поднять тяжесть.

Answer (score 0):

А может все проще?
Когда пьёшь крепкий напиток то дыхание перебивает. А в те времена такие напитки наверняка были "ого-го-го" какие ядреные))
Выпил, дыхание перебило и в груди начало от спирта греть)
Может выражение от этого и пошло?